# Airflow SSHOperator's Socket exception: Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, ssh, airflow, paramiko

In Airflow, I use an SSHOperator to call an API that works on some automation work. The work ran successfully and the report did generate, but Airflow returns the task failed due to the Socket exception.

This error sometimes occurs, and I would like to know the reason that caused it.

The error message received:

```
[2021-07-20 08:00:07,345] {ssh.py:109} INFO - Running command: curl -u <user:pw> <URL>
[2021-07-20 08:00:07,414] {ssh.py:145} WARNING -   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[2021-07-20 08:00:08,420] {ssh.py:145} WARNING - 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
[2021-07-20 08:00:09,421] {ssh.py:145} WARNING - 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
[2021-07-20 08:00:10,423] {ssh.py:145} WARNING - 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
[2021-07-20 08:00:10,615] {ssh.py:141} INFO - Report Sent Successfully.
[2021-07-20 08:00:10,616] {transport.py:1819} ERROR - Socket exception: Bad file descriptor (9)
[2021-07-20 08:00:10,633] {taskinstance.py:1481} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 152, in execute
    stdout.channel.close()
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 671, in close
    self.transport._send_user_message(m)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1863, in _send_user_message
    self._send_message(data)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1839, in _send_message
    self.packetizer.send_message(data)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 431, in send_message
    self.write_all(out)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 367, in write_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1137, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1336, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/u01/airflow-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 171, in execute
    raise AirflowException(f"SSH operator error: {str(e)}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error:
```

--- edit ---

```py
generate_report = SSHOperator(
    task_id = 'generate_report',
    ssh_conn_id = 'ssh_123',
    command = curl -u user:password "http://localhost:1234/path/to/trigger/report_creation_API?async=false",
)
```

Comment: The bad file descriptor error usually occurs when writing to a closed socket, reading from a write-only socket, or writing to a read-only socket. Post a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us reproduce your error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this error only occurs sometimes while the Airflow's SSHOpertaor works successfully and completes its jobs. Therefore, I have no code that can reproduce the error regularly, the code of the SSHOperator is updated for more information.

Comment: It sounds like this is environmental, then. Post more details about where the code is being run - for example, is it in a container? Does the machine you are SSHing to pre-emptively close the connection?

Comment: `SSHOperator` requires an `ssh_conn_id`, can you track what's happening to the connection ID? It's likely that's getting closed prematurely.

Comment: You can also attempt to move to your own [SSHHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook/index.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook.SSHHook) and see if that leads to the same problems. You can play around with `keepalive` and `timeout` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: The system runs in a VM which connects to other VMs via SSH, I will try working with SSHHook instead of using the SSHOperator to see if things are doing better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a race condition in paramiko library. A line above this close we are calling shutdown on read, and at the very beginning of the same method we are calling shutdown on write channel. This means that after the second shutdown the channel should be closed and likely this is what happens under the hood in paramiko library.

However this seems to happen asynchronously in a separate thread. Depending on which thread gets first, the socket can be already closed when we call `close()` in the operator. If the async thread in paramiko was faster, we are attempting to close an already closed socket and the error is thrown.

This is a classic `race` condition.

Since closing the closed connection is basically no-op operation, we can safely ignore such an exception. This is what I just did in the PR here:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17528

It will be released in the next wave of providers most likely (Which is likely and of August).

Comment: So should we treat the error message currently as a false alarm and wait for the next provider update (My version: 2.0.0) ?

Comment: Test. It's a false alarm.